# Converting a java application to ActiveX Object

Tags: java, activex

I have a java application. I got a requirement to change this application to an ActiveX object. Can anybody tell me is there any way to do it??

Comment: Which language will you use to write the ActiveX object?

Comment: If it can be written in JAVA then i would prefer JAVA. Actually i dont know much about ActiveX

Comment: Not sure you can do that. There are Java-based libraries out there (e.g. JACOB) that allows you to control an ActiveX object from Java, but not the other way round. One approach would be to use C++ to create the ActiveX component, then use a JNI to communicate between it and the Java code that you've already written. It's quite involved and you'd need a solid grounding in C++ and COM first.